# Context cannot be applied to a class

Tags: java, android

I've total three java files with names
MainActivity class, 
IncomingSMS class, 
DBManagement class

The IncomingSMS.java receive incoming sms and update inbox. The DBManagement.java have some method like (create, edit, update database etc).

I want to make a database with DBManagement.java class and add all incoming sms details to this database.

The problem is this, when i make an instance of DBManagement class into IncomingSMs class with `DBManagement dbManagement = new DBManagement(this);` the context problem arises and notify Context cannot be applied to (com.example.zohaib.ultimatesmsblocker.IncomingSMS.java).

kindly help me to resolve this issue.

IncomingSMS.java

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault(); // get object and subscription id of SmsManager
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); //Retrieve data from intent activity(sms data) and save to bundle
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); //get pdus messages from bundle, cast it to an Object[]
                //messageString = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]); //create message from pdu object
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getOriginatingAddress(); // get sender phone number
                    String messageBody = currentMessage.getMessageBody(); // get message text
DBManagement dbManagement = new DBManagement(this);
```

DBManagement.java

```
package com.example.zohaib.ultimatesmsblocker;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DBManagement extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "products";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productName";


    public DBManagement(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT, PRODUCTNAME TEXT)");
            Log.d("Create Database:", "Successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Create Database:", "not");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //add new product on a table row
    public boolean insertData(String product) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zohaib.ultimatesmsblocker">

    <!-- Give permission to read, receive, send sms -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".conversation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_conversation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I want to recieve incoming sms and save it to my own created database.**

Comment: I don't think you really want to be doing any database transactions in a `BroadcastReceiver`, but a `Context` is passed into the `onReceive()` method. Really, you should start an `IntentService` from the Receiver, and handle your database stuff there, which could include the inbox updates, as well.

Comment: can you post some code pls?

Comment: ok i will post shortly

Comment: please see code. @user3623735

Comment: Notice the `Context context` in `onReceive()`. Also, please heed the rest of my initial comment. And, as a heads up, I don't believe your code will work as you're expecting for multipart (long) messages.

Comment: please tell me how to save incoming sms to my own created database with DBManagement.java

Comment: Use the **context** not **this**. Also, @MikeM. got a point!

Comment: thanks i got solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the context that you get in on receive method.

```
DBManagement dnmanagement=new   DBManagement(context);
```